# Is the SWAP gate a Clifford Gate? How would I express it using the Clifford Gate generators?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, simulation, clifford-group

By my calculations, it looks like the SWAP gate is a Clifford Gate. See the following table:[image]

I follow the same method as in [this paper](http://home.lu.lv/%7Esd20008/papers/essays/Clifford%20group%20%5Bpaper%5D.pdf) for showing a gate is a Clifford Gate. I got the above table by performing calculations in Qiskit. How would I express the SWAP gate in terms of the generators of the Clifford group? The generators are the $H$ gate, the $S$ gate and the $CNOT$ gate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's well known that you can [make a swap out of three CNOTs](https://algassert.com/post/1717).

[image]

For reference, Stim's gate documentation includes H+S+CX decompositions of a lot of Clifford gates [including the swap](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SWAP):

```
Stabilizer Generators:

X_ -> +_X
Z_ -> +_Z
_X -> +X_
_Z -> +Z_

Unitary Matrix:

[+1  ,     ,     ,     ]
[    ,     , +1  ,     ]
[    , +1  ,     ,     ]
[    ,     ,     , +1  ]

Decomposition (into H, S, CX, M, R):

# The following circuit is equivalent (up to global phase) to `SWAP 0 1`
CNOT 0 1
CNOT 1 0
CNOT 0 1
```

Comment: thank you for the answer :) I saw before the the $C_{2}NOT_{1}$ and $C_{1}NOT_{2}$ gates can be used to make a $SWAP$ gate. My question then is:  how is the  $C_{2}NOT_{1}$ generated using the generators of the Clifford group?

Comment: $C_2NOT_1=(H\otimes H)\circ C_1NOT_2\circ(H\otimes H)$

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 That gate is considered to be in the gate set. But if you really want to go out of your way you can just surround a CNOT with Hs instead of switching the target and control roles.

Comment: hey @CraigGidney, do you (or perhaps someone you know) know the answer to my other question on Cliffords?: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/does-a-pauli-being-acted-on-by-a-random-clifford-get-sent-to-every-pauli-with-eq

Answer (score 4):

Yes, SWAP is a Clifford gate.

---

Your proof is correct. By definition, an $n$-qubit gate $U$ is Clifford if $UPU^\dagger\in G_n$ for all $P\in G_n$ where $G_n$ is the $n$-qubit Pauli group. However, it is easy to see that we only need to check that $UQU^\dagger\in G_n$ for $Q$ that are generators of $G_n$. Moreover, $G_n$ is generated by $\{i, Z_k, X_k\,|\,k=1,\dots,n\}$ where $X_k$ denotes the tensor product of Pauli $X$ on the $k$th qubit and identity applied to all other qubits and similarly for $Z_k$. Since $UiU^\dagger=iI\in G_n$ for all $U$, we only have to check that $UX_kU^\dagger\in G_n$ and $UZ_kU^\dagger\in G_n$ for $k=1,\dots,n$. This is exactly what the table in the question accomplishes.

---

It is easy to check that

$$
\text{SWAP} = C_1NOT_2 \circ C_2NOT_1 \circ C_1NOT_2\tag1
$$

where $C_iNOT_j$ denotes the CNOT gate with qubit $i$ as control and $j$ as the target, e.g. by applying both sides of $(1)$ to the computational basis states.

Comment: thank you for the answer :)

Comment: see my comment in the other answer.

Comment: do you (or perhaps someone you know) know the answer to my other question on Cliffords?: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/does-a-pauli-being-acted-on-by-a-random-clifford-get-sent-to-every-pauli-with-eq

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps might be of interest to provide a full proof that the SWAP operation is equal to the $3$ CNOT gates described in the other answers. A very interesting way to prove this is using the [ZX-calculus](https://zxcalculus.com/). We only need the following re-writing rules, known as (1) the *bialgebra rule* and (2) the *Hopf rule*.

Equation (1):

[image]

Equation (2):

[image]

The proof is taken from [this reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.13966.pdf).

First, translate the circuit description in terms of the calculus,

[image]

Now, using the fact that maintaining the connectivity one can change freely the diagram we have the following equations:

[image]

Which concludes the proof. Apart from the non-trivial rules we also used fusion of spiders and that the white or grey circles as gates are equivalent representations of the identity.

Comment: that's really cool, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 I am happy that it was interesting!